# Reading and writing to GD25B32CPIG flash memory

Tags: arduino-uno, spi, flash

I recently removed a GD25B32CPIG flash memory chip from a commercial coin-operated arcade game. Apparently it has all the game's sounds stored directly on the chip. I decided to see if I can learn to communicate with the chip to read the current data and write new data to it so that I can possibly change the game's sounds as the game itself doesn't have the ability to do that.

After searching online, I found [schematics](https://www.gigadevice.com/datasheet/gd25b32c/) for the chip, including its functions and pinouts.

[image: Pinout of the GD25B32CPIG]

I've wired it up to my Arduino Uno's MOSI, MISO, CK, and SS pins as well as the 3.3V and GND for power. This is the only part I know is correct.

Unfortunately, I am lost on what to do next since I've never used the SPI library by itself (normally other libraries handle the SPI connections in my other projects). Nobody else has a tutorial on this particular chip and I'm a little bit lost by the datasheet's commands. I also did some research on SPI and found the tutorials to be a bit confusing.

I haven't tested anything because I don't want to alter the data unless I know what I'm doing.

### The question:

Is there a way to read all data at once and write to a particular register?

Comment: https://github.com/Marzogh/SPIMemory may work.